# Read contact was display contact only from email storage

Tags: java, android

I want to create feature to read all contact number from my contact with sim 1 and 2 contacts, contacts from email storage and contacts from phone storage. But, in my app only contact from email storage is getting displayed. 
Some one please help me.

Here is my code to fetch contacts.

```
public class ContactUtils {
    //get contacts from phonebook
    public static List<PhoneContact> getRawContacts(Context context) {
        List<PhoneContact> contactsList = new ArrayList<>();

        Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = new String[]{
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
        };

        String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '1'";
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

        // Build adapter with contact entries
        Cursor mCursor = null;
        Cursor phoneNumCursor = null;

        try {
            mCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

            while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
                //get contact name
                String name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

                //get contact name
                String contactID = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
                //create new phoneContact object
                PhoneContact contact = new PhoneContact();
                contact.setId(Integer.parseInt(contactID));
                contact.setName(name);


                //get all phone numbers in this contact if it has multiple numbers
                phoneNumCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[]{contactID}, null);

                phoneNumCursor.moveToFirst();


                //create empty list to fill it with phone numbers for this contact
                List<String> phoneNumberList = new ArrayList<>();


                while (!phoneNumCursor.isAfterLast()) {
                    //get phone number
                    String number = phoneNumCursor.getString(phoneNumCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));


                    //prevent duplicates numbers
                    if (!phoneNumberList.contains(number))
                        phoneNumberList.add(number);

                    phoneNumCursor.moveToNext();
                }

                //fill contact object with phone numbers
                contact.setPhoneNumbers(phoneNumberList);
                //add final phoneContact object to contactList
                contactsList.add(contact);

            }

            mCursor.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (mCursor != null)
                mCursor.close();
            if (phoneNumCursor != null)
                phoneNumCursor.close();
        }

        return contactsList;

    }


//format number to international number
//if number is not with international code (+1 for example) we will add it
//depending on user country ,so if the user number is +1 1234-111-11
//we will add +1 in this case for all the numbers
//and if it's contains "-" we will remove them
private static String formatNumber(Context context, String countryCode, String number) {

    PhoneNumberUtil util = PhoneNumberUtil.createInstance(context);
    Phonenumber.PhoneNumber phoneNumber;
    String phone = number;
    try {
        //format number depending on user's country code
        phoneNumber = util.parse(number, countryCode);
        phone = util.format(phoneNumber, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL);

    } catch (NumberParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //remove empty spaces and dashes
    if (phone != null)
        phone = phone.replaceAll(" ", "")
                .replaceAll("-", "")
                .replaceAll("\\(","")
                .replaceAll("\\)","");

    return phone;


}

//get the Contact name from phonebook by number
public static String queryForNameByNumber(Context context, String phone) {
    String name = phone;

    try {
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phone));

        String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME};

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                name = cursor.getString(0);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return name;
    }
    return name;

}
```

I will to display all contact from my contact list, not from email storage only

Answer (score 0):

```
  ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phone="";
            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                //Query phone here.  Covered next
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    // Do something with phones
                    phone = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                }
                pCur.close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you have some issues in your code, but non of them explain your main complaint, you should be getting ALL phones of ALL contacts on your device, including those saved on the sim cards.

Do you have contacts saved on your sim card that are not picked up by this code?
Can you add a new contact on your sim with some special phone number like `1111111`, and add a log in case your code gets to that phone in your loop?

Some things I would change in order to improve your code and fix some other issues:

1. Change from `ArrayList<PhoneContact>` to `HashMap<Long, PhoneContact>` as a mapping from Contact ID to a PhoneContact object
2. remove your selection/selectionArgs/sortOrder vars, you're not using them anyway
3. remove the second cursor code under `//get all phone numbers in this contact if it has multiple numbers`, instead check the HashMap to see if that CONTACT_ID was already added to the map and if so, add the new data to the same PhoneContact object. Your existing code would create many duplicates of PhoneContact for the same contact in case that contact has multiple phones
4. Add a log for ACCOUNT_TYPE and ACCOUNT_NAME to your loop for each row, so you can see in the log what is the source of the data (Gmail, local storage, SIM, etc.)
5. remove the try/catch you have, if there's some crash in your main loop you want it to crash the app so you can understand and fix the issue, if you do have a crash, it might explain why you're not seeing all the data

You can see a similar code in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57131613/819355